# Socket.io doesn't work on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm new to node.js and socket.io. I test sample applications that posted on http://socket.io/#how-to-use. Everything's fine on Opera, IE and Safari but nothing happens on Chrome and Firefox.

Versions
Node.js - v0.10.5
Socket.io -0.9.6
Chrome - 27.0.1453.116
Firefox - 21.0

Comment: Do any errors show up in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Nothing show on chrome but web socket connections are pending so long and on Firefox displays The connection to ws://localhost/socket.io/1/websocket/uCV4q8mI4ocBD7IC8jxC was interrupted while the page was loading.

Comment: For what it's worth, for me the first example shows the object logged in the console, i.e. the example works, in Firefox 21; but in Safari 5.1.9 there are GET requests that constantly poll, and I don't see anything in the console.

Comment: I should say, that I entered http://localhost:8888 in a browser (after changing the port number in the example).  Am I supposed to do something different?

Comment: That is the same problem. I tested on many ports but problem persist on my Chrome 27.0.1453.116 and Firefox 21. There are GET requests constantly poll.

Comment: dunno its working on my chrome `27.0.1453.116` are you sure its not an firewall?

Comment: Sure, other browsers work well. But Chrome and Firefox works only with Secure Web Sockets

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug around Web Socket and some modern browsers.Even [this test](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) will not work. Read the following issues.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1150
991 and 998